# Getting a single random object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm working on a page that will generate into a mustache template in the html page a random object from an array (I only want one object's data on the screen at any time). I stuck figuring out how to do the code for the button that will pull the random object. I was wondering if anyone might know how to do this. Here is the JS code:

```
GameList.fetch({
    success: function(resp) {
        var dataObj = {"data":resp.toJSON()};
        console.log(dataObj);
        globalDataObject = resp.toJSON();
        var gameTemplate = $("#gameTemplate").text(); 
        var gameHTML = Mustache.render(gameTemplate, dataObj);
        $("#gameInject").html(gameHTML);
        console.log("success: ", resp);
    }, error: function(err) {
    console.log("error: ", err);
    }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function () {
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
}, routes: {
    "newGame/:objectId": "chooseGame",
    "":" index"
}
});

$("#chooseGameButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newGame.set({
        number: $("#number").val(),
        name: $("#name").val(),
        description: $("#description").val(),
        equipment: $("#equipment").val(),
        where: $("#where").val(),
        image: $("#image").val(),
        URL: $("#URL").val()
    })
})
```

Comment: With some array `A` you can do `A[Math.floor(Math.random()*A.length)]` to get a random element.

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation and where's the array you want to select randomly from?

Answer (score 0):

If your array is `myArray`, here is how you get a random element from it.

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var randIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

var myRandomElement = myArray[randIdx];
```